# Loopback custome login access token

Tags: node.js, model, loopbackjs, loopback

I want to validate user information against my database and when success create a  token, but i keep getting an error that says the createAccessToken is undefined.

'use strict';

```
module.exports = function(server) {
  // Install a `/` route that returns server status
  let SystemModel = server.models.Systemuser;
  let UserModel = server.models.User;
  let router = server.loopback.Router();
  var TWO_WEEKS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2;
  router.get('/', server.loopback.status());
  router.get('/login', function(req, res) { // test login
    SystemModel.findOne({
      'where': {
        'username': 'Gabrielle',
      },
    }).then(function(results) {
      // do some password processing
      UserModel.createAccessToken(...) // it says it does not exists
    }).catch(function(reason) {
      console.log(reason);
    });
    res.json({'name': 'hello'});
  });
  server.use(router);
};
```

How can I use the build in User model just to create tokens.

Answer (score 0):

`createAccessToken` is a method of an **instance** of `User`.

If your `Systemuser` extends `User`, then you should be able to call `results.createAccessToken(timeToLive, cb)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello This can help u:

```
 user.accessTokens.create({
            created: new Date(),
            ttl: Math.min(ttl || user.constructor.settings.ttl,
                user.constructor.settings.maxTTL),
        }, cb);
```